# Laravel 4.1 Facade Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am attempting to create a facade within laravel 4.1. I have created the facade, service provider and the class, to no avail. I followed numerous "how to's" including the advanced video for custom facades on Laracasts. No matter how many times I try, I end up with the exception of `Non-static method Custom\Helpers\Helper::doSomething() should not be called statically`

Here is my code...

**HelpersServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Custom\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelpersServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('trial','Custom\Helpers\Helper');
    }

}
```

**HelpersFacade.php**

```
<?php namespace Custom\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;


class Helper extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'trial';
    }

}
```

**Helpers.php**

```
<?php namespace Custom\Helpers;
class Helper {
     public function doSomething()
     {
        return 'Hello';
     }
}
```

I add the service provider to my app.php file and register the facade alias

```
'Custom\Helpers\HelpersServiceProvider',

'Helper'         => 'Custom\Facades\Helper',
```

Then when I try to access it via a Static call (yes, I know it's not really static) or via the service provider directly I get the exception error.

Scratching my head on this one...

Comment: I assume you ran `dump-autoload` and whatnot?

Comment: Your assumption is correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an incorrectly named class (or file):

> HelpersFacade.php

```
class Helper extends Facade {
```

Additionally, your `Helper` class is in `Helpers.php`.  Those need to match, also.

Comment: I renamed both files to Helper.php, ran composer and I still receive Non-static method Custom\Helpers\Helper::doSomething() should not be called statically

Comment: if you put a die statement in your facade file outside of the class, does it get hit?

Comment: also, be sure to re-dump your autoload after changing the filenames

Comment: Hi watcher, I always dump :) That said, I did add die into the Helper.php facade file and it did NOT get hit, I instead get the static exception.

Comment: You should fix the class names, then try my previous answer.

Comment: Jason, the class name of Helper is now the same as the two file names and I did run composer afterwards with no success. Am I missing something?

Comment: Jason your previous comment was to run composer dump-autoload was it not? I have done that and it still doesn't work.